# Unable to restart Apache, getting error: apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}

Tags: apache2

I am getting this error trying to restart Apache, does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks,

Comment: what command did you try to restart apache ?

Comment: Are you using `sudo apache2`? Try `apache2ctl` instead. See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/147065/56343

Comment: do a source envvars & then run your command.

Answer (score 10):

To fix this problem, you have to make the changes to two separate files.

First, edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, adding these lines:

```
User www-data
Group www-data
```

Second, edit `/etc/apache2/envvars`, adding these lines:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Comment: The first block can probably keep referencing the environment variables; the crucial step is defining them in `/etc/apache2/envvars`!

Comment: Actually, my environment variables (Ubuntu 12 VPS which I don't have a lot of control over) were set up correctly and were not referenced. The `User www-data` is the fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

This will set your apache2 ENV vars for the current session and allow you to use the apache2 binary without modifying your config:

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

/etc/apache2/envvars

Is simply a script that sets some environment variables. When you use apachectl it processes this before launching apache2 itself. If you want to invoke apache2 from the terminal, you'll need those vars as well.

So invoking `source /etc/apache2/envvars` sets up the variables allowing apache2 to work outside of apachectl.

You could potentially set these up in a number of other ways. E.g. invoke envvars when you login.

Comment: /etc/apache2/envvars simply sets some environment variables. When you use apachectl it processes this before launching apache2 itself. If you want to invoke apache2 from the terminal, you'll need those vars as well. So invoking source /etc/apache2/envvars sets up the variables allowing apache2 to work outside of apachectl.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, by restarting the machine the error went away (I had just installed apache2) and I was able to issue the command `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and have apache2 restart.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary fix (that I used) was to edit the file in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Look for this:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

and change it to this:

```
User www-data
Group www-data
```

For whatever reason, apache2 isn't looking in `envvars` to get the appropriate environment variables. The real answer to why this is happening is to track down why `envvars` isn't being consulted.

Comment: Probably an upgrade that did not affect configuration. `/etc/init.d/apache2` is supposed to load this variable. You can manually extract the conffile from a deb file and replace it.

Comment: Really? What does your `/etc/apach2/apache2.conf` say around line 144? I'm wondering what it has for User and Group. This seems bizarre to me because envvars defines it and its right next to apache2.conf.

Comment: Use `apt-get download apache2.2-common` and `dpkg -x apache2.2-common*.deb fs` to extract files to a directory called `fs`. You can then check it yourself. (this is at least the case with Oneiric and Precise)

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Got this when I tried `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2 -k restart`.

 Actually apache2 in /usr/sbin was link to shared library '/lib/apache2/mpm-worker/apache2' 
 Instead `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` should be used as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to run `apache2 -M` also.

I ended up just sourcing the envars file like this:

```
. /etc/apache2/envvars
```

That set the environment variable properly since running apache2 outside of the standard init script.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `apache2 -M` I got the same error.  Found this solution:

```
groupadd sshusers
```

I have no idea why this fixed it, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

manually edit `/etc/group` and add `www-data` there then start apache

add `www-data:x:1012:www-data` at end of file and save it Ctrl-X Yes {enter}
   (1011 was last num in my group file)

start apache
`sudo service apache2 start`

it worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the sane problem and checked `apache2ctl status` and it said I needed to configure `www-browser` or adjust `apache_lynx`

My shell told me to install lynx, so I did, and that solved it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```